# Añadir atributos a los campos de un formulario de contacto desde un Model.Form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

**Entorno**: django 1.11.4, python 3.5

**Form.py**

```
class ContactoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    widgets = {
        'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Name'}), #no funciona
    }
    class Meta:
        model = Contacto
        fields = ('nombre', 'email', 'telefono', 'mensaje', )
```

**Contacto.html**

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="" novalidate="novalidate">{% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset>

                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input name="contactName" type="text" id="contactName" value=""                         minlength="2" required="" aria-required="true"
                                class="full-width">

...Continua 
                      </fieldset>
       </form>
```

Quiero usar los atributos que se usan en widgets del ModelForm para añadirlos al input text,no me funciona,el campo no se modifica. alguna idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te estás confundiendo, `widgets` es un atributo que debes pasarle al `Meta` del formulario:

```
class ContactoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Contacto
        fields = ('nombre', 'email', 'telefono', 'mensaje', )
        widgets = {
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Name'}),
        }
```

La otra opción es sobreescribir el campo:

```
class ContactoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    nombre = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Name'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Contacto
        fields = ('nombre', 'email', 'telefono', 'mensaje', )
```

Pero prefiero la primera opción, es más entendible.